# Timeout issue in JTA container managed transaction

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jta

I am using eclipselink jpa for my database interactions. I need to process a large number of data, make a webservice call and the response has to be inserted in a table. The overall process takes little long may be 30mins based on the number of users. 
I am using container managed transactions using the below annotations.

> @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyAppPU")
>           private EntityManager em;
>
> @Stateless @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)

When the program runs for longer time, gettig the timeout exception as below.

> `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active
>   - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction
>   timed out after 123 seconds BEA1-0A674B56FA04CB79C16B]'. No further
>   JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.

Can anyone please suggest any solution or workaround for it?

Comment: Have you tried to set connection timeout > 30 minutes manually?

Comment: Yeah, I can see that option but do not have access to the server. That can be considered as the last option by requesting to the tech services team. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Any other way from the code to achieve it?

Comment: don't you configure timeouts on your side? If so, you can set timeouts in your configuration files (see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/index.html?org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html ). I don't get it where PersistenceUnit comes from.

Comment: If the timeout is a transaction timeout, then only container configuration can control it.  JPA has no control of the transaction when container managed, it just registers listeners with the transaction to get callbacks to do its work on commit.  I'd look at your process though, as 30 minutes seems very long, and a lot can go wrong.  You might try to shorten your transaction or break it up first.

Comment: Its a batch kind of job which has to process a huge data of around 1 lac users. I see in the documentation that it can be increased as much as we need. Is it a good practice to extend the timeout duration and what can be the maximum practical value?

Comment: Depends on your system and what you need to do.  The longer the transaction, the higher the risk of random network errors and other issues cropping up that would prevent it from completing, and of course, the longer that resource can be tied up unusable by anyone else.

Comment: @user1611498 which server are you using ? Is it weblogic ?Then try following these steps https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0407settingthetransactiontimeoutonwe01.html